# How does the "Compare Branches" feature of Github desktop work?

Tags: github, github-desktop

I have a branch with just a few small differences with the base `develop` branch. It was refreshed from /synced with `develop` two hours ago.  Running `git diff` we see *six* changed files and just under 200 lines of difference.

Instead `github desktop compare branches` feature shows *55* files and over 4K SLOC

[image]

Why is the Compare Branches showing all the *changes* to my current branch instead of the *differences* with the compared to branch [`develop`]  ?